# Add a set of related models to serializer output in django w djange-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I am just getting familiar with django and django-rest-framework.
I have a model of Jobs that have an owner, and I want to add the list of jobs a user owns to the user endpoint.

I tried to do it like this, as the tutorial of the django rest framework says:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    jobs = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True, queryset = Job.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'jobs')
```

But for some reason, when I want to view the users, I recieve 
 AttributeError at /users/
'User' object has no attribute 'jobs'

The documentation about the PrimareyKeyRelatedField looks just like this. Do I maybe have to do something with the user model?

What works is the following:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'job_set')
```

but I don't like  that solution as I want to have more control about how the list is presented (maybe change the ids to complete json objects or rename the attribut name from 'job_set' to 'job)

I really don't now what I am overseeing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things,

`jobs = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True, source='job_set' queryset = Job.objects.all())`

or

Set `related_name='jobs'` attribute to User relational field.

Comment: The `related_name='jobs'` was what I was missing, thanks!